# android testing on samsung galaxy tab

Tags: android, eclipse, galaxy-tab

Is it possible to test my android app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab using Eclipse?  I know there is no USB connection for the Galaxy Tab so how does the device get connected to Eclipse?

Comment: Since when is there no USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. Enter Settings->Applications->Development and there check the "USB debugging" checkbox. If it is grayed out, then open Settings->Wireless and Network->USB settings and select the "Ask on connection" option. After this you should be able to enable USB debugging and start developing apps on your galaxy tab

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I plan on buying a Galaxy Tab this week and start testing.  I have to wait 3 months before I can buy a Samsung phone so the Tab will really expedite my testing.